# File Type Icon not updating in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, registry, file-type, .ico

So long story short, I followed the instructions here to have my program open when a specific file type is double clicked.
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58005-file-associations-in-visual-studio/

I included an Icon to be associated with the specified file type.  The problem that arises is that when I go back to update/change that icon image and attempt to reinstall a newer version of the program, the old icon is used and not the one I changed it to be in visual studio...

Comment: The OS keeps a cache of these icons. This may be the source of your problem. If so, clearing the cache should fix it.  Try searching for "windows icon cache rebuild".

Answer (score 3):

The icon is probably cached in the shell icon cache. Delete `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db` (and kill explorer or log off) on NT6 or use [TweakUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweak_UI) on older systems.

Comment: This is indeed the problem. Thanks everyone for the good and quick responses, being a total nooby programmer, is there any way I can do this programmatically in the solution/deployment?

Comment: This problem is more common on a development machine, I would NOT recommend that you try to delete the cache on the end-users machine. Call SHChangeNotify if VS is not doing it for you, that is the documented way and should be enough in normal scenarios...

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SHChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern void SHChangeNotify(int wEventId, int uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);

SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)null);//SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED SHCNF_IDLIST
```

Comment: So after attempting to call SHChangeNotify, it does not seem to be refreshing. What I found interesting though is the open file dialog in my program (using the c# library) shows the updated icon but If I were to go through windows explorer, the file icons remain the same...(this occurred prior to using SHChangeNotify)

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to make the icon to update: 1. overwrite the old .ico file in the project folder (or wherever it's kept) with the new file - this will update the icon in the Application Properties. 2. Edit the Mainform, go to the icon property and re-select the icon file - this update the icon shown on the window and the task bar.